# OpenSIPS Azure signalling does not forward call

Tags: azure, opensips

I try to migrate an OpenSIPS implementation 2.4.1 from our regular datacenter to Azure.
I use standard residential script with NAT enabled, registrant and dynamic routing module. Calls come in fine and routing module is working. Problem is I cannot forward the call based on routing module to the same internal IP on another port to an asterisk instance.

My config :

```
...
listen=udp:10.209.xx.xx:5060 as 40.xx.xx.xx:5060

alias=udp:40.xx.xx.xx:5060
alias=udp:10.209.xx.xx:5060
...
```

Debug :

```
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:drouting:do_routing: using dr group 1, rule_idx 0, username xyz
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:drouting:internal_check_rt: found rgid 1 (rule list 0x7f81e3cc2490)
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:drouting:push_gw_for_usage: adding gw [Dries] as "sip:0123456789/xyz@10.209.xx.xx:5070" in order 0
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:drouting:push_gw_for_usage: setting GW id [Dries] as avp
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:tm:t_newtran: transaction on entrance=(nil)
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:core:parse_headers: flags=ffffffffffffffff
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:core:parse_headers: flags=78
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:tm:t_lookup_request: start searching: hash=48689, isACK=0
/usr/sbin/opensips[21038]: DBG:tm:matching_3261: RFC3261 transaction matching failed
```

Comment: are there any actual error logs below the lines you posted?  Can you do `xlog("XXX - $ru - $du\n")` right before you call `t_relay()`?

Comment: Meanwhile I solved it and learned :

for what is Azure concerned :

1. Always talk to the public IP address - even for registrant and drouting dr_gateways; Opensips takes care of translating to internal addresses.

2. Protect asterisk on the other port on the same VM using Azure NSG, since you talk to it via its public IP.